# Optimize a SQL Server query with conditional and formatted string join

Tags: sql, sql-server, conditional-statements, inner-join

I need to execute a query that will join two tables on fields named `a.PatientAddress` and `b.ADDRESS`, the issue is that `b.ADDRESS` needs to be standardized and formatted to match the standardized address found in `a.PatientAddress`.  I don't have control over the incoming data format, so having the data scrubbed before it comes into my `b` table is not an option. Example:

`a.PatientAddress` may equal something like `1234 Someplace Cool Dr. Apt 1234` while the matching address in `b.ADDRESS` may equal something like `1234 Someplace Cool Dr. #1234` (in reality that is just one of many possibilities).  The Apartment number (if existent in the address) is the area of fluctuation that needs formatting in order to join properly.

Some possible Apt variations I've seen in the data set are:

- 1234 Someplace Cool Dr. #1234
- 1234 Someplace Cool Dr. Apt 1234
- 1234 Someplace Cool Dr. Apt #1234
- 1234 Someplace Cool Dr. Apt # 1234

Now, for what I've already tried;

```
    SELECT  vgi.VisitNo
            ,vgi.AdmitDate
            ,vgi.ChargesTotal
            ,MONTH(vgi.AdmitDate)           AS AdmitMonth
            ,DATENAME(MONTH, vgi.AdmitDate) AS AdmitMonthName
            ,YEAR(vgi.AdmitDate)            AS AdmitYear
            ,vgi.PatientAddress
            ,mm.MAIL_DATE
            ,mm.ADDRESS

    FROM    VISIT_GENERAL_INFORMATION vgi
            INNER JOIN MARKETING_MAILING mm ON vgi.AdmitDate >= mm.MAIL_DATE
                AND vgi.AdmitDate > '2014-01-01 00:00:00.000'
                AND (
                    -- IF APT IS NOT FOUND, THEN ADDRESS SHOULD DIRECTLY EQUAL ANOTHER ADDRESS
                       (    mm.ADDRESS NOT LIKE '%[$0-9]'
                            AND UPPER(vgi.PatientAddress) = UPPER(mm.ADDRESS) 
                       )
                       OR
                       (
                             mm.ADDRESS LIKE '%[$0-9]'
                             AND UPPER(vgi.PatientAddress) = 
                             -- PATIENT ADDRESS SHOULD EQUAL THE FORMATTED ADDRESS OF THE MAIL RECIPIENT
                             -- GET THE FIRST PART OF THE ADDRESS, UP TO THE ADDRESS NUMBER
                             SUBSTRING(mm.ADDRESS,1,CHARINDEX(REPLACE(LTRIM(RIGHT(mm.ADDRESS, CHARINDEX(' ', mm.ADDRESS)-1)),'#',''),mm.ADDRESS))
                             + ' ' + 
                             -- GET THE APARTMENT ADDRESS NUMBER AND FORMAT IT
                             -- TAKE OUT EXTRA SPACING AROUND IT AND THE # CHARACTER IF IT EXISTS
                             REPLACE(LTRIM(RIGHT(mm.ADDRESS, CHARINDEX(' ', mm.ADDRESS)-1)),'#','')
                       )
                    )
```

The problem here is that the query takes 20+ minutes to execute, and sometimes doesn't even finish before the operation time expires.  I've also tried splitting the two conditions up into `UNION` statements.  I've also tried splitting the street address and apartment number to create a like statement that reads `UPPER(vgi.PatientAddress) LIKE UPPER('%1234 Someplace Cool Dr.%1234%')` and that doesn't seem to work either.  I'm starting to run out of ideas and wanted to see what others could suggest.

Thanks in advance for any pointers or help!

Comment: Consider not standardizing on the fly. Add a calculated field, index it. THen join with this field. And string joins are pretty much a "welcome to hurt slow, you asked for it" slow.

Comment: What type of calculated field? What would the `calculation` be?

Comment: Your joing. The normalization. This avoids doing it on the fly and allows indexing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logic needed to scrub the data is beyond the scope of what we can do for you. You'll likely find that, ultimately, you **need** some other key for this query to ever work. However, assuming your existing logic is adequate to create a good match (even if slow), we might be able to help improve performance a bit.

One way you can improve things is to join on a projection of the address table that cleans the data. (That means join to a sub query). That projection might look like this:

```
SELECT Mail_Date, Address, 
           CASE WHEN ADDRESS LIKE '%[$0-9]' THEN
                    -- GET THE FIRST PART OF THE ADDRESS, UP TO THE ADDRESS NUMBER
                    SUBSTRING(ADDRESS,1,CHARINDEX(REPLACE(LTRIM(RIGHT(ADDRESS, CHARINDEX(' ', ADDRESS)-1)),'#',''),ADDRESS))
                    + ' ' + 
                     -- GET THE APARTMENT ADDRESS NUMBER AND FORMAT IT
                     -- TAKE OUT EXTRA SPACING AROUND IT AND THE # CHARACTER IF IT EXISTS
                     REPLACE(LTRIM(RIGHT(ADDRESS, CHARINDEX(' ', ADDRESS)-1)),'#','')
                ELSE UPPER(ADDRESS) 
           END AS ADDRESS_CLEAN
FROM MARKETING_MAILING
```

This improves things because it avoids the "OR" condition in your JOIN; you simply match to the projected column. However, this will force the projection over every row in the table (hint: that was probably happening anyway), and so it's still not as fast as it could be. You can get an idea for whether this will help from how long it takes to run the projection by itself.

You can further improve on the projection method by adding the `ADDRESS_CLEAN` column above as a [*computed column*](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250.aspx) to your Marketing_Mailing table. This will force the adjustment to happen at insert time, meaning the work is already done for your slow query. You can even index on the column. Of course, that is at the cost of slower inserts. You might also try a view (or [materialized view](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933148.aspx)) on the table. This will help Sql Server save some of the work it does computing that extra column across multiple queries. For best results, also think about what `WHERE` filters you can use at the time you are creating the projection, to avoid needing to every compute the extra column on those rows in the first place.

An additional note is that, for the default collation, you can skip using the UPPER() function. That is likely hurting your index use.

Put it all together like this:

```
SELECT  vgi.VisitNo
        ,vgi.AdmitDate
        ,vgi.ChargesTotal
        ,MONTH(vgi.AdmitDate)           AS AdmitMonth
        ,DATENAME(MONTH, vgi.AdmitDate) AS AdmitMonthName
        ,YEAR(vgi.AdmitDate)            AS AdmitYear
        ,vgi.PatientAddress
        ,mm.MAIL_DATE
        ,mm.ADDRESS

FROM    VISIT_GENERAL_INFORMATION vgi
        INNER JOIN 
           (
               SELECT Mail_Date, Address, 
                   CASE WHEN ADDRESS LIKE '%[$0-9]' THEN
                       -- GET THE FIRST PART OF THE ADDRESS, UP TO THE ADDRESS NUMBER
                       SUBSTRING(ADDRESS,1,CHARINDEX(REPLACE(LTRIM(RIGHT(ADDRESS, CHARINDEX(' ', ADDRESS)-1)),'#',''),ADDRESS))
                       + ' ' + 
                        -- GET THE APARTMENT ADDRESS NUMBER AND FORMAT IT
                        -- TAKE OUT EXTRA SPACING AROUND IT AND THE # CHARACTER IF IT EXISTS
                        REPLACE(LTRIM(RIGHT(ADDRESS, CHARINDEX(' ', ADDRESS)-1)),'#','')
                   ELSE ADDRESS END AS ADDRESS_CLEAN
                 FROM MARKETING_MAILING
            ) mm ON vgi.AdmitDate >= mm.MAIL_DATE
                    AND vgi.AdmitDate > '2014-01-01 00:00:00.000'
                    AND vgi.PatientAddress = mm.ADDRESS_CLEAN
```

Another *huge* factor not yet covered is indexes. What indexes are on your `VISIT_GENERAL_INFORMATION` table? I'd especially like to see a single index that covers both AdmitDate and PatientAddress. Which order is determined by the cardinality of those fields, and how clean and how much data is in the Marketing_Mail table.

Finally, one request of my own: if this helps, I'd like to hear back on just how much it helped. If the query used to take 20 minutes, how long does it take now?

Comment: I agree about scrubbing beyond our ken, however in the example he gave removing `#` and `Apt` would be quicker don't you think?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @TomTom that you would really benefit from "pre-standardizing" into either

- a derived column that updates on the fly
- or a view or just a temp table in your query process

that gives you a clean match.

And with that, I would use a third-party service or library, ideally, because they have spent a lot of time making it a reliable parse.

Either option works after receiving the data you can't control, so that is not a problem.
What you're doing is creating your own, internal copy that is standardized.
Of course, you're going to need to run the other side, "a", through the same standardization.

Comment: actually, it looks like @Joel covered this...  +1 there